# When I declare function in useEffect, it is not declared in html

Tags: reactjs

I am implementing to change the `state` depending on it is hovered or not. But if I make it like the first code below, `Too many re-renders.` error will occur. In order to solve this problem, I used the useEffect to render only when the `state` changes, but an error called `onHover is not defined` occurs that the function declared in the user effect was not declared.

**not using useEffect**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <button onMouseEnter={setIsHover(true)} onMouseLeave={setIsHover(false)}>
      click
    </button>
  );
}
```

**using useEffect**

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const onHover = () => {
      setIsHover(true)
    }
  },[isHover])

  return (
    <button onMouseEnter={onHover()} onMouseLeave={setIsHover(false)}>
      click
    </button>
  );
}
```

What should I do to use the function declared in useEffect?

Comment: You're calling the function in the prop immediately, rather than passing it to be called. Try `onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)}` (and the same change in the other prop) to avoid the render loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you just want to setState so no need to use useEffect.
You can use without using useEffect as below.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <button onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}>
      click
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with scope. The `onHover` function is defined within the `useEffect` hook, so it goes out of scope once you're out of the hook's block. You'll have to define it directly inside the component, outside of any other block scope, and simply *call* it inside `useEffect`.

It will still result in `onHover` called so many times until the mouse leaves the element in question. To prevent it, you could add a condition like so:

```
const onHover = () => {
  if (!isHover) {
    setIsHover(true);
  }
}
```